# Adding label to map layer by clicking feature or similar action in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I have searched the web (including stack exchange) quite extensively and haven't found anything. I've tweaked the 'repeat' setting on the label position tab on a line layer to where it labels enough features without me having to delete a ton of duplicates. But there are still some lines that are not labeled at all (complex stream network). I'd like to *add* a label for these streams. Ideally, I could click the stream and it would populate the name into the label automatically. But I'd be plenty happy to click the label location and type it in by hand. I just need to get the label on the map.

Am I missing something?

I am using QGIS 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **SuperLabeling** plugin:

> **Add your label by mouse click only.**
>
> Some other similar plugins already exist, which create a memory layer or other layer making somehow difficult to integrate data. This plugin creates label data in the existed files in a minimum manner. You don't even need to type any thing, just mouse clicking can make be helpful to your work. After you click the 'Start Edition', you can just use left click to select position of label and implement the labeling process. Also, you can do left double clicking to hide the label.

---

You can select a field for the values to appear as labels when you click on a feature on the map. If no labels are present in the attribute table, you can always enter it manually but the location of the label would remain. You can download this from the menubar:

```
 Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it 1) deleted all of my existing labels for the layer and 2) didn't produce any labels when I clicked a feature. Is there any documentation for the plug-in? And there's no other out-of-the-box means of adding a label to a map? Thanks again

Comment: @Debaser - There are various function in the **Label Toolbar** you could check. There's also the **EasyCustomLabeling** plugin.